# WebAPI doesn't maintain FormsAuthentication over controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, controller

This is the situation:

I own an AccountController, which inherits from ApiController, that looks something like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Login")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login()
    {
        string emailOrUsername = base.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ElementAt(0).Value;
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(emailOrUsername, false);
        return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, emailOrUsername);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [ActionName("Logout")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hope to see you again!");
    }
```

I also own an MessageController, which also inherits from ApiController, that looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ActionName("ReceiveMessage")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ReceiveMessage()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Successfully received your message");
    }
```

So, AccountController works perfectly, I login and am able to logout.
This is where the tricky and confusing part begins. As I'm testing on the same computer (localhost), I am able to access ReceiveMessage once I am authorized.
So far so good.

I have now edited the Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config and edited the binding:
binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":60967:"

So I can access my WebApi from another device. I can Login and Logout, but I cannot access ReceiveMessage (with login made) from this new device - while on the localhost I can do whatever I want.

What am I doing wrong? (This is a sample, I'm planning on having multiple users connection to the api, so having a static var somewhere is not an option)

Comment: Which device? Does that device support cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser wise works just fine, @charlie Brown is correct, the issue is cookie related -- I was acessing it from an unity application